# HTML to MS Word Template

Tags: html, ms-word

I am generating a HTML page from a Java EE application that contains Labels to use for printing addresses on envelopes.  This just consist of a straight HTML.

The user wants to be able to copy and paste from the web page into a MS Word Template (see [Letter Template](http://www.pintum.com.au/labels.doc)

However when copy and pasted all the text is squashed into the 1st labels box. Is there a way I can structure my HTML so that when it is paste into Word it get split across each box.

Or is my only option to generate a PDF or MS word document from Java manually.

Comment: POI lets you use Java to generate Word documents: http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I have solved my own issue already

If I place my HTML into a table of 3 columns (as that matches the Label template I am using)
Then before pressing paste into MS Word I Select All, then press paste it seems to split the labels into each section correctly.